# Extracting links with specific class using css selectors

Tags: python, html, css, scrapy

I have the following HTML structure
I want to extract all the links with the **class:dev-link**

```
<a class="dev-link" href="mailto:info@jourist.com" rel="nofollow" title='Photoshoot"</a>
```

I am using the below code to extract the link in scrapy

```
response.css('.dev-link::attr(href)').extract()
```

I am getting the correct output but is this the right way to use css selectors??

Comment: if you are using python, why not using regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in [Scrapy Documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html)  there are two methods to scrap data, *CSS Selector*  and *XPath Selector* both are works correctly but XPath needs some practice to get expert, in my opinion, Xpath is more power in special cases you can scrap data easier that CSS selector ( but of course you can get them with CSS selector too),

what you did is correct

```
 link = response.css('.dev-link::attr(href)').extract_first()
```

and also you can get it with the following too

```
link = response.xpath('/[contains(@class,’dev-link’)]/@href').extract_first()
```